# Jquery: Passing functions as vars

Tags: javascript

I am learning jquery through this website, and I am really confused about how passing functions as vars (if I am phrasing this correctly) is done. Take this example:

```
function makeAddFunction(amount) {
  function add(number) {
    return number + amount;
  }
  return add;
}

var addTwo = makeAddFunction(2);
var addFive = makeAddFunction(5);
show(addTwo(1) + addFive(1));
```

I understand that makeAddFunction(2) says: "makeAddFunction takes variable amount, so pass 2 to it".
I don't understand two things:

1. What "happens" when you declare a variable (addTwo, and addFive) as a function? Does the var = the result of the function, or does it = a reference to the function?
2. How can (1) be passed to addTwo/addFive (in the last line of code) when addTwo/addFive do not accept any arguements? Furthermore, how does (1) make it through to the "number" variable in function add?

Thank you!

Comment: first, it has nothing to do with jquery, those are javascript features

Comment: the second part is called as [Closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Closures)

Comment: `makeAddFunction` returns a function (a different one each time you call it). That makes both `addTwo` and `addFive` functions. So you can call them and pass them arguments just like you could with any other function.

Comment: Right.. but how does addTwo(1) send the (1) all the way to the "number" variable of the function "add"? I mean if anything you are passing (1) to makeAddFunction variable "number" not "amount"...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ad 1.

Step by step:

`var addTwo = makeAddFunction(2);`

becomes

`var addTwo = function (number) { return number + 2; };`

it is equivalent to:

`function addTwo(number) { return number + 2; };`

so addTwo do accept an argument

Ad 2.

`show(addTwo(1) + addFive(1));`

becomes

`show((1 + 2) + (1 + 5));`

`show(3 + 6);`

`show(9);`

Comment: Ohhh, hold on. Does var "addTwo" become function(number)... because in makeAddFunction, we are returning "add" ?

Comment: @user3585210, `makeAddFunction` returns `add` and `add` is a function, yes.

Answer (score 0):

`makeAddFunction` return a function reference. With a function reference, you can call it.

When doing `makeAddFunction(2);`, the important thing to check is what it return. As you can see, it return `add` which is an other function. So in fact, doing `var addTwo = makeAddFunction(2);` is exactly the same as

```
var addTwo = function add(number) {
    return number + 2;
}
```

As a proof, check what you can do :

```
console.log(makeAddFunction(2)); //Will Log function add(){...}
console.log(makeAddFunction(2)(1)); //Will Log 3
```

You are in fact only creating "dynamic function", or the proper name for it : [Closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Closures)